# Export panda dataframe with coloured cell to excel

Tags: python, pandas, excel, export

I have a script in pandas that imports an excel with a table with numbers. A few cells had the numbers with the sighn <. The script eliminate the "<" in certain cells and divide the number in the those by two. After that it marks as red the cell in which > has been eliminated. But I can't export to excell correctly.

```
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
```

```
COLUMN_NAMES = ['reception_date', 'day', 'PM10', 'PM2,5', 'SO42--S', 'NO3-N', 'HNO3-N+NO3--N', 'NH3-N+NH4+-N']

class CellValue:
  def __init__(self, input):
    self.value = None
    self.is_fixed = False
#I eliminate < in certain cells and I divide by two the number.
    try:
      if isinstance(input, str):
          if "<" in input:
              value = input.replace('<', '')
              value = value.replace(',', '.')

              self.value = float(value)/2
              self.is_fixed = True
          else:
            self.value = float(input)
            self.is_fixed = False

          return
    except:
      self.value = np.NaN
      return

    self.value = float(input)
    
  def __format__(self, fmt):
    return format(self.value, fmt)

Read excel.
df = pd.read_excel('data/PRODUCTS.xls', sheet_name='G', names=COLUMN_NAMES)

df = df.set_index('day')

df = df.query("not day.isnull()")
df = df[1:]
df['PM10'] = df['PM10'].apply(lambda x: CellValue(x))
df['SO42--S'] = df['SO42--S'].apply(lambda x: CellValue(x))
df['NO3-N'] = df['NO3-N'].apply(lambda x: CellValue(x))
df['HNO3-N+NO3--N'] = df['HNO3-N+NO3--N'].apply(lambda x: CellValue(x))

#I mark as red the cell which had <

df \
  .filter(['reception_date', 'day', 'PM10', 'SO42--S', 'NO3-N', 'HNO3-N+NO3--N']) \
  .style \
  .applymap(lambda x: "background-color:tomato;" if x.is_fixed else "", subset=['PM10', 'SO42--S', 'NO3-N', 'HNO3-N+NO3--N']) \
  .format('{:.4f}', subset=['PM10', 'SO42--S', 'NO3-N', 'HNO3-N+NO3--N']) \
  .format(lambda x: f"{x.day}/{x.month}/{x.year}", subset=['reception_date'])
```

type here

```
The table is

reception_date  PM10    SO42--S NO3-N   HNO3-N+NO3--N
day                  
1   6/10/2022   3.0000  0.2000  0.0708  0.2062
2   6/10/2022   7.0000  0.3914  0.1286  0.2633
3   11/10/2022  6.0000  0.2366  0.1320  0.2209
4   11/10/2022  10.0000 0.4301  0.2673  0.3598
5   11/10/2022  4.0000  0.1691  0.0750  0.2068
6   11/10/2022  39.0000 0.6583  0.3527  0.4269
7   11/10/2022  19.0000 0.5306  0.2705  0.3792
8   11/10/2022  48.0000 0.8703  0.5877  0.6940
9   11/10/2022  7.0000  0.2131  0.1118  0.2275
10  20/10/2022  4.0000  0.2034  0.1326  0.2094
11  20/10/2022  12.0000 0.4766  0.3002  0.3860
12  20/10/2022  13.0000 0.4995  0.3335  0.4307
13  20/10/2022  6.0000  0.0698  <0.0200 0.1369
14  20/10/2022  4.0000  0.1563  0.0400  <0.0700
15  20/10/2022  10.0000 0.0824  0.0205  0.1588
16  20/10/2022  6.0000  0.2029  0.1020  0.1614
17  27/10/2022  10.0000 0.3160  0.1699  0.2714
18  27/10/2022  nan nan nan 0.1859
19  27/10/2022  8.0000  0.1123  0.0100  0.1463
20  27/10/2022  12.0000 0.2823  0.0607  <0.0700
21  27/10/2022  3.0000  0.0569  0.0100  0.1495
22  27/10/2022  nan nan nan 0.1376
23  27/10/2022  7.0000  0.0884  0.0200  0.1496
24  3/11/2022   5.0000  0.1489  0.0337  0.1710
25  3/11/2022   2.0000  0.0764  <0.0200 <0.0700
26  3/11/2022   4.0000  0.1178  0.0627  0.2071
27  3/11/2022   nan nan nan 0.1488
28  3/11/2022   7.0000  0.1376  0.0200  0.1565
29  3/11/2022   8.0000  0.1876  0.0163  0.1858
30  3/11/2022   5.0000  0.1987  0.0929  0.2106
31  10/11/2022  9.0000  0.2943  <0.0200 0.1792
```

I tried to export as excel with

```
df.to_excel('/content/RESULTS.xlsx')
```

But the result was
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/4kmsp.png)

The table should be something like this
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/iJxVk.png)

How can I export to excel? Thank you.

Comment: I believe the lambda function applying the class to each item is returning a class object. Instead you want it to be returning the Class.Value property